# What is the benefit of dockerize the SPA web app

Tags: docker, nginx, web-applications, single-page-application

I dockerize my SPA web app by using nginx as base image then copy my nginx.conf and build files. As [Dockerize Vue.js App](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html) mention I think many dockerizing SPA solutions are similar.

If I don't use docker I will first build SPA code then copy the build files to nginx root directory (After install/set up nginx I barely change it at all)

So what's the benefit of dockerizing SPA?

----- update -----

One answer said "If the app is dockerized each time you are releasing a new version of your app the Nginx server gets all the new updates available for it." I don't agree with that at all. I don't need the latest version of nginx, after all I only use the basic feature of nginx. Some of my team members just use the nginx version bundled with linux when doing development. If my docker image uses the latest ngixn it actually creates the different environment than the development environment.

I realize my question will be probably closed b/c it will be seen as opinion based. But I have googled it and can't find a satisfied answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few benefits.

Firstly, building a Docker image means you are explicitly stating what your application's canonical run-time is - this version of nginx, with that SSL configuration, whatever. Changes to the run-time are in source control, so you can upgrade predictably and reversibly. You say you don't want "the latest version" - but what if that latest version patches a critical security vulnerability? Being able to upgrade predictably, on "disposable" containers means you upgrade when you want to.

Secondly, if the entire development team uses the same Docker image, you avoid the challenges with different configurations giving the "it works on my machine" response to bugs - in SPAs, different configurations of nginx can lead to different behaviour. New developers who join the team don't have to install or configure anything, and can use any device they want - they can be certain that what runs in Docker is the same as it is for all the other developers.

Thirdly, by having all your environments containerized (not just development, but test and production), you make it easy to move versions through the pipeline and only change the environment-specific values.

Now, for an SPA, these benefits are real, but may not outweigh the cost and effort of creating and maintaining Docker images - inevitably, the Docker image becomes a bottleneck and the first thing people blame. I'd only invest in it if you see lots of environment-specific pain (suggesting having a consistent run-time environment is necessary), or if you see lots of "it works on my machine" type of bug.

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't use docker I will first build SPA code then copy the build files to nginx root directory (After install/set up nginx I barely change it at all)

This is a security concern... fire and forget is what it seems is being done here regarding the server.

If the app is dockerized each time you are releasing a new version of your app the Nginx server gets all the new updates available for it.

Bear in mind that if your App does not release new versions in a weekly bases then you need to consider to rebuild the docker images at least weekly in order to get the updates and keep everything up to date with the last security patches.

> So what's the benefit of dockerizing SPA?

Same environment across development, staging and production. This is called 100% parity across all stages were you run your app, and this true for no matter what type of application you deploy.

If something doesn't work in production you can pull the docker image by the digest and run it locally to debug and try to understand where is the problem. If you need to ssh to a production server it means that you automation pipeline have failed or maybe your are not even using one...

Comment: I have been using docker for a year. I know one of its goals is to solve "that did not happen in my environment" problem. I just don't see how that applies to SPA development b/c npm build files are the same, ngixn versions are same even without docker. Also check my updated question.

Comment: I should rephrase that you get all updates for the Operating System in the container and all installed programs. If you not keep your software up to date you are opening security holes in your infrastructure, no matter if in containers, VMs or bare metal. Continuous Integration should detect when new updates breaks you setup.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like Webpack compile Javascript applications to static files that can then be served with your choice of HTTP server.  Once you’ve built your SPA, the built files are indistinguishable from pages like `index.html` and other assets like image files: they’re just static files that get served by some HTTP server.

A Docker container encapsulates a single running process.  It doesn’t really do a good job at containing these static files *per se*.

You’ll frequently see “SPA Docker containers” that run a developer-oriented HTTP server.  There’s no particular benefit to doing this, though.  You can get an equally good developer experience just by developing your application locally, running `npm run build` or whatever to create a `dist` directory, and then publishing that the same way you’d publish other assets.  An automation pipeline is helpful here, but this isn’t a task Docker makes wildly simpler.

(Also remember when you do this that the built application runs on the user’s browser.  That means it can’t see any of the Docker-internal networking machinery: it can’t use the Docker-internal IP addresses and it can’t use the built-in Docker DNS service.  Everything it reaches has to be on `docker run -p` published ports and it has to use a DNS name that reaches the host.  The browser literally has no idea Docker is involved in this at all.)

Comment: I have to say I don't see the benefit of using docker here.